# Why is terminal blank after running python executable?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, executable

I added the *hashbang* line at the beginning of the python script (`#!/usr/bin/python`) and gave it executable privileges via `chmod +x file.py` command but after clicking on the module to run it, the terminal pops up but is blank.

Would it have something to do with the python interpreter possibly not being in the specified path?

Comment: I see no bang. The _shebang_ you desire is `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: sorry, i edited the post to include the exclamation mark. script had the exclamation mark but terminal is still completely blank after clicking on script to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that that is not a valid *shebang*.

Try `#!/usr/bin/python`

(Note the exclaimation after the hash mark.)

**Edit in response to comments from OP:**

So, based on your comments about clicking the icon in a file manager and the platform being *LXDE*, it looks like in that use case it ends up calling into the `g_app_info_create_from_commandline` function from the [GAppInfo](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.35/GAppInfo.html) library, which appears to be a whole layer for storing "application information and launch contexts".

Before that, it ends up bitwise-OR'ing in the `G_APP_INFO_CREATE_NEEDS_TERMINAL` flag into the `flags` field that it passes off to `fm_app_info_create_from_commandline` in the [*fm-file-launcher.c* code](https://github.com/lxde/libfm/blob/0ad53a6b350f66bde58011115b915264d53eab9f/src/base/fm-file-launcher.c).

So, it looks like double-clicking on the file is doing a ton of extra stuff before eventually running it in a terminal, and it would appear that that extra stuff (additional context, abstracted out via other libraries and layers, etc.) is what's causing the issue.

If the feature is really supposed to truly launch things in a terminal "normally", then I would regard it as a bug in the *fm-file-launcher.c* code or perhaps in the *GAppInfo* code itself.

I'm not sure the developers would necessarily agree -- it will depend on what exactly is going on under the hood and what they intended that feature to be exactly. If you really want to be able to do this (I'm not sure I really get the benefit over simply using the `./file.py` method directly in a terminal window), I would recommend filing a bug against the *fm-file-launcher.c* code. That is part of the *libfm* project, and it appears they don't track issues via their *github* page, but rather, their SourceForge page, according to their [forum](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=0&t=575&sid=6793fba6462ab01a1537624fdf7f4f36).

In short, double-clicking on the icon in the file manager and choosing to launch it in the terminal vs. actually launching it in a terminal are very, very different things, even if the former is meant to essentially function like the latter.

As a side note, I tried doing this in *Nautilus* (I use *Ubuntu*), and its behavior for that use case is to just automatically assume it's a text file and not an executable and load it into my default text editor.

Comment: thanks for quick response Ken. I apologize. I forgot to type the exclamation mark in the post but I actually did include the exclamation mark after the hash and no success.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Hmm... what do you mean by **clicking on the module to run it**? Are you not running it like `./file.py` from the terminal window? If not, what happens if you do?

Comment: Yeah it works fine if i run it from the terminal window using ./file.py but when i want to run it as an executable by clicking on the file icon, the terminal will pop up but it will be blank.

Comment: Hmm... do you mean you double-click the icon for file.py in, say, Nautilus (if Ubuntu; or are you on OS X)?

Comment: right. after double-clicking the icon for file.py in ubuntu (LXDE) it will say "This text file 'factorial.py' seems to be an executable script. What do you want to do with it?" then i click on "execute in terminal" After which a terminal pops up but is blank.

Comment: Wow Ken! you definitely went above and beyond. I really appreciate it. Thanks for clarifying that double-clicking on icon and choosing to launch in terminal are very different things. I didn't quite think about that possibly being the case. Perhaps you're right in that simply executing from terminal isn't less beneficial than executing via icon in file manager. I just wanted to cover all grounds/basis for knowing how to execute a python module for the purpose of best practices. I'm an aspiring developer so you'll have to forgive me but do you know how python modules are executed in practice?

Comment: I also wanted to upvote you but i need 15 reputation points lol.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I use *Python* often as a dev. and I can't think of a case where I've wanted to be able to launch it from an icon. Perhaps if you had a *GUI* app. for end users, although even then I'd use a shell wrapper script. Generally I invoke from a shell, or even more often, via a *crontab* on a server to run on a schedule.

Re: upvoting, you could accept my answer with your current reputation, as I think I've pretty much answered your question. =)  The devs for the code I mentioned earlier would need to answer the specifics as to exactly why it's blank in a bug report if you open one.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* have something to do with the script not actually being set to print anything out. Remember, while all statements get printed output if run directly in the interpreter, for example,

```
>>> a = 2
>>> a ** a
4
```

would show in the intrepeter, but you would need a `print` statement (function in P3k) for the output to be shown if run as a script.

Comment: thanks. yeah there's a print statement in the script, well it first has a prompt for input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have something to output the items to the terminal like for your file.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "test"
```